# how to flip an image on click of a button and stop flipping when another button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i want to make a checkbox when clicked will flip an image continously and when other button is clicked the image will stop flipping.Its more like an ac simulator, where when i click the swing button the image starts flipping, but when i click off button, nothing happens. pls help.

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="">


 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <style>

 body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
background-image: url('wall paper.jpg');
background-repeat: cover;
width:0px;
height:0px;
}

   form{
 width: 380px;
 height: 370px;
 padding:30px 15px 15px;
 background: lightblue;
}

 input[type = "button"] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 65px;
  background :white;
   margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:20px;
  border:20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 400px;
 }

 label {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 220px;
  margin-top: 320px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200%;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
 transform: rotateX(320deg);
  }
 }

img.b {
  margin-top: -650px;
  margin-left: 500px;
}

:checked + .card {
  animation: rotation 7s infinite linear;
}

input[type = "text"] {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  background:white;
  text-align:right;
  font-size: 60px;
 }

img.c {
  margin-left: 330px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  width: 473px;
  height: 55px;
 }

</style>

<input type="text" id="myText" value="">
<p id="demo"></p>

<label>
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="card">
<div class="front"><img src="plate.jpg" class = "c"></div>
</div>
</label>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#j").click(function(){
  $(".c").stop();
  });
});

function n() {
AC.display.value = 20;
}

function o() {
AC.display.value = "";
}

function d() {
AC.display.value = AC.display.value - 1;

if(AC.display.value === 0) {
AC.display.value = "";
}

if(AC.display.value <= 16) {
AC.display.value = 16;
}
}

function t() {
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
setTimeout(o, x * 1000);
}

function i() {
AC.display.value++;

if(AC.display.value === 0) {
AC.display.value = "";
}

if(AC.display.value >= 32) {
AC.display.value = 32;
}
}

</script>
</head>

 <body>
 <form name = "AC">
 <input class = "value" type = "text" name = "display" disabled><br>

<input type = "button" name = "btnD" value = "DECREASE" onclick = "d()">
<input type = "button" name = "btnI" value = "INCREASE" onclick = "i()">
<input type = "button" name = "btnO" value = "ON" onclick = "n()">
<input id = "j" type = "button" value = "OFF" onclick = "o()">
<input type = "button" name = "btnT" value = "TIMER" onclick = "t()">
<input class = "flip" type = "button" name = "btnS" value = "SWING">
<img src = "openac.jpg" class = "b" width= "550" height= "200">
 </body>
 </html>
```

when the checkbox is clicked it flips the image, but when the off button is clicked nothing happens.(sorry beacause of the messy code.)
pls help. thnx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see how to create a [MRE] with just the code that we need to see the problem. This will make it easier for us to see the code we need to help with , and will also help you to fix up the mistakes in your code that might be contributing to the problem :) At the moment your HTML is invalid because you have HTML element in the `head`

Comment: Simply have the spinning styling tied to a class and have the clicks add / remove that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
var img = $('.card');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#j").click(function() {
    img.css("animation-play-state", "paused");
  });
  $('label input, .flip').click(function() {
    img.css("animation-play-state", "running");
  });
});

function n() {
  AC.display.value = 20;
}

function o() {
  AC.display.value = "";
}

function d() {
  AC.display.value = AC.display.value - 1;

  if (AC.display.value === 0) {
    AC.display.value = "";
  }

  if (AC.display.value <= 16) {
    AC.display.value = 16;
  }
}

function t() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  setTimeout(o, x * 1000);
}

function i() {
  AC.display.value++;

  if (AC.display.value === 0) {
    AC.display.value = "";
  }

  if (AC.display.value >= 32) {
    AC.display.value = 32;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('wall paper.jpg');
  background-repeat: cover;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

form {
  width: 380px;
  height: 370px;
  padding: 30px 15px 15px;
  background: lightblue;
}

input[type="button"] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 65px;
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 400px;
}

label {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 220px;
  margin-top: 320px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(320deg);
  }
}

img.b {
  margin-top: -650px;
  margin-left: 500px;
}

.card {
  animation: rotation 7s infinite linear;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 60px;
}

img.c {
  margin-left: 330px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  width: 473px;
  height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myText" value="">
<p id="demo"></p>

<label>
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="card">
  <div class="front"><img src="plate.jpg" class = "c"></div>
</div>
</label>
<form name="AC">
  <input class="value" type="text" name="display" disabled><br>

  <input type="button" name="btnD" value="DECREASE" onclick="d()">
  <input type="button" name="btnI" value="INCREASE" onclick="i()">
  <input type="button" name="btnO" value="ON" onclick="n()">
  <input id="j" type="button" value="OFF" onclick="o()">
  <input type="button" name="btnT" value="TIMER" onclick="t()">
  <input class="flip" type="button" name="btnS" value="SWING">
  <img src="openac.jpg" class="b" width="550" height="200">
</form>
```

Comment: actually, when i tried that but, it worked half. like, when i refreshed the page the plate automatically started to flip and when i clicked the off button it will stop flipping. (this is actually what i want). but, when it flips automatically, i don't want that to happen, like only when i click the checkbox at that time it should start flipping and when i click the off button, it should stop there. hope you understood my query.

Comment: You want it to flip automatically for the first time page loads, right? If that's what you want, I have updated the code for that. I'll explain the changes when you'll be satisfied with output.

Comment: well, no. when the page starts, i want the image to stay still and not flip. And when i click the swing button or that checkbox, i want the image to flip. and when i click the off button it should stop flipping and stay still. Also thank you for the code and the explanation.

Comment: @swastikapallai can you please check this code again (I have edited). I hope this is what you desire.

Comment: thank you, I have reached my goal. thank you for that explanation.

Comment: @swastikapallai if it's done, please mark the answer correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The question asks why clicking the OFF button does not stop the swinging.

Clicking OFF calls function o which clears the AC.display.value It does nothing else. Nowhere in the code does it seem that the AC.display.value is used other than to set it to various values when different buttons are clicked.

By contrast, the image that is swinging does so via a CSS animation which gets set by this CSS

```
:checked + .card {
  animation: rotation 7s infinite linear;
}
```

so it correctly swings/doesn't swing on a 'toggle' i.e. when the box is checked or not.

Some of the other buttons also change AC.display.value but they do not do anything else.

I suspect (but don't know) that this value is intended in some way to influence the amount and/or the timing of the swing.

As @FluffyKitten pointed out, the HTML has some problems with being mis-placed in the header, and some of the other code is, as @swastika pallai says, a bit messy.

The first thing to solve is to find out exactly what the changeable value in the top box is to be used for and make sure it is used for that - perhaps either to change the timing of the animation (which can be done through animation-duration) or the amount of swing or....

A second action would be to go through the HTML deciding what is actually a button, what is a checkbox and so on and sort the order out so it is clearer as to what is going on.